# how to change post header title/heading on default blog posts-page

Tags: wordpress, blogs, posts

It seems like my theme has a "feature" that changes my normal page header when i set a default post-page. Every time I set a default page for the blog-posts (readings: set page for the posts-page), the theme changes that pages title, and replaces it with “Latest News” in the centre. It appears this might be a "feature" of my theme, peakshops, but their support has gone dark.

I can't find where this is located. I can see in a code inspector this thing looks like some sort of "archive-title" class... so I'm wondering if there are some css changes i can make to change the title from "latest news" to anything else. When i click on the inspector i shows me this:

```
<div class="archive-title search-title">
        <div class="row align-left text-left">
            <div class="small-12 medium-8 large-6 columns">
                <h1>
                    Latest News</h1>
                                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And maybe if anyone knows how to find where that is hidden, i can then change it! I’d welcome some help please! Thanks much

The page I need help with: https://www.byjgk.com/blog/

Comment: This is so ambiguous, you should try to find where that title is because you can't just use a filter like that if there is no support for it.

So, why don't try to remove that "Latest news" <h1> there, and just test it?. By the way, your question should remove "And I hate it"...

Comment: @asfo - yes I've been  hunting around trying to find where that header is, but so far no dice! I updated the question based on your input.

Comment: What happens if you change the `<h1>` then?

Comment: hello, I can't find the actual page where this code is located (I'm not very skilled in this stuff). e.g. I can just use the "inspector" to see the code, but when i try to search around the different sections (style.css, or page.php, etc) looking for where that code is, I can't find it. If you have any idea where that above code is located, I could go to that page and change it? Thanks!